# Compile Veins models with c++14

Tags: c++, omnet++, veins

I want to use PyTorch with Veins due to which I need to compile the code using C++14 standard. I looked up OMNET++ and Veins documentation but found nothing.

I am using macOS (11.5) and Ubuntu (18.04 and 20.04). I could install the precxx11 version of PyTorch for Ubuntu but there is no such option for macOS. Hence, I have no other option but to use C++14.

How would I go about achieving this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check `configure.user` change (uncomment) the `CXXFLAGS` variable there and set it to `-std=c++14`, then run `./configure` and then clean/rebuild OMNeT++ and all of your models so everything would use C++14 as default. OMNeT++ 6.x is using C++14 by default.

Comment: My solution worked as well but I wanted to mark this as the accepted answer as it seemed less hacky.

Answer (score 1):

I added the following line at the end of the [makefrag](https://github.com/sommer/veins/blob/master/src/makefrag) file:

```
CXXFLAGS += -std=c++14
```